# cannot resolve symbol 'currentActivity'

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"), PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

        }
```

I use this code to pick file from phone storage

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //error
            return;
        }
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            File file = FileUtil.from(currentActivity , uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then, it say it say **cannot resolve symbol 'currentActivity'**.

Comment: If you don't see the problem here, I would strongly suggest you step back from Android and focus on learning Java (or Kotlin) first. Otherwise you are in for a world of pain trying to figure out the complexities of Android and distinguishing "android" problems from "language" problems. Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because currentActivity isn't a defined variable.  Since onActivityResult is most likely in an Activity class, use `this` instead.